# Do AppleScripts invoked by Mail filters have access to the e-mail(s) that matched the filter?

Tags: macos, email, applescript

I’m setting up a filter in Mail on OS X that calls an AppleScript whenever an e-mail sent to a specific e-mail address arrives.

Will the AppleScript get passed/have access to any of the e-mail’s properties? I’d like it to take different actions based on the “from” e-mail address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: if the script invoked by the filter has a `perform mail action with messages` handler, then the `messages` argument will be populated with a list of the messages that matched the rule.

See http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20040602114525386